# Java, SQLite, Insert data to Database

Tags: java, sqlite

I have a SQLite database, with these parameters

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "people_table";
private static final String COL1 = "ID";
private static final String COL2 = "name";
private static final String COL3 = "anything";
```

Here's how it's created:

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + "TEXT)" ;
```

I'm trying to add data to the db, for both columns, my code is here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    contentValues.put(COL2, "item");
    contentValues.put(COL3, "item2");

    long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);

    if (result > 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

But it is not working, I have no idea why.
Please, any advice?

Comment: result will only ever be 1 once, try using **> 0** i.e. `if (result > 0) {` (note this assumes that id is defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (with or without autoincrement))

Comment: thanks, updated it, but didnt solve the problem

Comment: you need to provide more details. The table create definition and how you are invoking the above. Oh and delete the App's data and or uninstall the App and try again.

Comment: updated with table create

Comment: Not working means little. Is it crashing? If so edit question to include stack-trace. Are you not getting the expected results, if so show how you are ascertaining those results that you use to conclude that nothing is being inserted.

Comment: It returns false, so no data inserted

Comment: Change insert to insertOrThrow and try again (should crash) copy stack-trace into the your question.

Comment: If this is your actual code then you miss a space in your create statement. Instead of `COL3 + "TEXT)"` write `COL3 + " TEXT)"`. Then uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: OK spotted issue. space missing for COL3 definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you have omitted a space so there is no column named **anything**, but instead a column named **anythingTEXT**

Change to use :-

```
String createTable = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT, " + COL3 + " TEXT)" ;
```

Then delete the App's data, or uninstall the App and rerun.

- This is required as the onCreate method only runs when the database is first created.